# Is "we all pull on one single string" an idiom or is it just wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, idioms

> We all pull on one single string.

Is this correct English?

When I look up the intended meaning of this phrase, I get the following results from several online dictionaries:

- 

> to pull together
>
> > to act in concern
>
> But there is no dictionary that says, "to pull on one (single) string".

Hence my question: Is it an idiom or is it wrong?

Addition: This phrase is definately meant to be an idiom. There are no physical strings to be pulled. It means to say that everyone holds together to face a common dread, to make a difference and to fight for a better world. Thats the context.

Comment: What exactly is the "real world problem" here? Did you come across this phrase somewhere? Is it your own coinage?

Comment: Where did you read this expression/idiom? Could you post a link? The idioms I know of are "to pull strings", "pull a few strings" and "to pull **the** strings".

Comment: This expression was written by a friend of mine. He wrote a songtext for our band. That's why i want to check this ;)

Comment: @Gordon: Are you and/or your friend native English speakers? I think you mean ***lyrics***, not ***songtext***, and I suspect this question is effectively proofreading for non-native speakers.

Comment: Singing from the same songsheet.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker. And my friend who wrote the phrase said that english would be his mother tongue. oh jo i meant "lyrics". Sorry for that ;)

Comment: You might find [ell.se] a more suitable place for future questions. And I suspect you meant, "to act in concert," not, "to act in concern." Lastly, please use proper capitalization when asking for help here. This is a site dedicated to and run by English enthusiasts. Please, no more lower-case "i", no more "english", and go easy on the emoticons.

Comment: I get a sense here that you're not really meaning "idiom", but rather "metaphor".

Answer (score 3):

The idiom I know is [all pulling in the same direction](http://idiom-a-day.blogspot.co.uk/2010_09_01_archive.html).

Comment: I'm more used to the basic concept expressed as [we all pull together](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we+all+pull+together%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but I suspect it all nets down to the same thing. OP has either found a bad translation, or it's a (probably, also bad) attempt at "creative writing". One person may indeed ***pull strings***, but several people pulling on the same string doesn't create a credible image for me.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't an idiom that I recognize but it is correct English in the sense that it is a valid English sentence. It would, however, need some external context to make sense. I have no idea why you'd want to pull on a string or why many different people would want to pull on the same string. Whatever the original meaning was it is lost without the context. What that context could be is something I have having trouble imagining.

> Ever since our second string broke, we all pull on one single string.

Guessing at the non-idiomatic meaning is well outside the scope of EL&U.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The phase is definately meant as idiom by the one who wrote it. But it seems that there is no such idiom...

Comment: It really amazes me how native speakers of English don't understand idioms that are so obvious in other languages. If 20 people pull together on one string, they all work together to achieve the same outcome. They help each other. This saying is derived from a sport where two parties each pull on one end of a rope. The party who is stronger and pulls the other party over a white line drawn on the pavement wins. Obviously, in order to win, you have to have more manpower to win. So the correct saying in my native language would be 'Y'all have to pull on one string'

Comment: @Chris Perhaps the issue is the word "string". "String" usually implies a small, fragile string of material. "We all pull on the same rope" probably comes much closer to the intended meaning -- especially for a game of tug-of-war.

Answer (score 0):

*[in unison](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+unison)*! but used in a metaphoric sense.

Not an idiom, not literal, but it's literary.

Your friend sure has written nice lyrics (songtext).

A kind of a take on *We are all [on the same boat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+in+the+same+boat)* with rewording appropriate for the context of a band.

With some luck, it may one day even become an idiom, who knows; and your band, famous. :)